# calculate uptime/downtime for a service

Tags: c#

I have a custom solution that checks if a web-site is online, every 1 hour.

The result is something like this: (there is one entry per day)

[image]

There are 24 entries in a day (every hour). And every hour has a availability percentage (100%, 95%, 0% ... and so forth).

My questions are:

- how can I get up-time and downtime in percentage?
- how can I calculate up-time and downtime using these values between 2 dates `DateTime` and get the result in seconds?

The up-time is easy:

- sum of all values divided by 24 (entries) which is 99.67%

Then for downtime, can I just do 100 - 99.67 = 0.33 % ?

I have some issues in getting the up-time/downtime in seconds between 2 dates `DateTime`

For example: if the range dates are 20.04.2015 - 26.05.2015

I think I should do like this:

For each day calculate the up-time as above (sum of all daily values divided by 24 entries) and assuming the following values:

- 20.04.2015: 96.67%
- 21.04.2015: 100.00%
- 22.04.2015: 92.00%
- 23.04.2015: 96.67%
- 24.04.2015: 100.00%
- 25.04.2015: 100.00%
- 26.04.2015: 100.00%

Now the sum of the above values divided by the number of days (7 days between 20.04 and 26.04) which makes `97.91 %` availability between 20.04 and 26.04.

I assume to get 97.91 % up-time in seconds I should do like this:

```
 CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

 DateTime first = DateTime.ParseExact("20.04.2015", "dd.MM.yyyy", provider);
 DateTime last = DateTime.ParseExact("26.04.2015", "dd.MM.yyyy", provider);

 TimeSpan time = last - first;

 decimal secondsUptime = ((time.Days * 86400)/100) * 97.91m;  //97.91 is the uptime calculated above for the time period. 

 // The problem is how to get this?

 decimal secondsDowntime = ?
```

What I have done so far, is this the correct approach?

How to get the secondsDowntime?

Comment: Simple.  Make a table with 24 rows one for each hour.  Then get the hour of each value and enter a value into the table.  The percentage is the number of entries in the table divided by 24.

Comment: I have the table already, all data is stored properly. Number of entries divided by 24? So if I have 7 entries (one entry per day) between the mentioned dates above and divide that per 24 will be 0.29, percentage for what?

Comment: If you already know how to calculate the up time percentage, what's the problem of doing `100-UpTimePrecent` to get the down time percentage? The time span of the calculation is irrelevant to this part of the calculation.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I did that already, I just wanted to be sure that is the correct approach. The main issues I have is getting the downtime/uptime in seconds between two dates. Please check the whole post. Sorry I made it so long.

Comment: You should take a look at "TotalSeconds", btw.

Comment: @Robert: do you mean instead of `time.Days * 86400` use `time.TotalSeconds` ?

Comment: Remember there are days having 23 and 25 hours respectively - summer/winter time changes.

Comment: @OndrejTucny There are also days where there are 23 hours 59 minutes and 59 seconds. This will allow you to have > 100% uptime.

Comment: @Aron the point is even in tgat case uptime may only be <= 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the Up time percent, All you have to do is very simple math:

```
decimal PercentDownTime = 100 - PercentUpTime;
decimal SecondsUpTime = (time.Seconds / 100) * PercentUpTime;
decimal SecondsDownTime = (time.Seconds / 100) * PercentDownTime;
```

Thanks to [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1901272/robert) for reminding us the [`TotalSeconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `TimeSpan`, but In this case it's ok to use the [`Seconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.seconds(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you meant in your comment. So basically calculate also the downtime for the period as 100 - uptime then calculate the seconds the same way as for up-time. Great. You opened my eyes :) However I think I will go with @Robert suggestion using `time.TotalSeconds` instead of calculating the `days * secondsInOneDay`. Thank you one more time!

Comment: I've edited my answer, giving credit to Robert as well.

Comment: Or `time.Seconds` also :)

Comment: Glad it works now. There is a lot of handy stuff in the .net toolbox.

Comment: @Aron The Summer times and leap seconds are a problem, but they are not a problem related to my suggested solution

Answer (score 1):

Hold up... Ur input numbers are wrong. If u measure once per hour and display the hourly results than how does ur 11:00 have 97%? It should be 100% or 0% its either up or down that hour.... Unless u actually do more calculations in that hour... But even then to get 97 u would have to do at least 100 tests that hour and 3 of them were down.

But if ur numbers are correct the formulas are this...

**Uptime % = (sum of the uptime percentages) / (number of measurements) × 100**

**Uptime % = (sum of uptime) / 24 × 100**

**Downtime % = 100 - (uptime %)**

**Seconds of uptime = (number of hours measured or to consider) × 3600 × (uptime %) / 100**

**Seconds of downtime = (number of hours measure or to consider × 3600) - (seconds of uptime)**

**Note** 3600 is the number of sec in an hour so we multiply the hours by that to get us to the wanted time unit of seconds.

**Note** Replace uptime % with a number between 0 and 100. Not 0 and 1. If u use 0 to 1 then dont do the last division by 100.

Comment: The values mentioned are dummy values, however there is another system that does the actual checking + additional calculations and savings of the data. My example was just for demo purpose :)

Comment: Fail on assumption of 24 hours each day.

Comment: Thats not 24 hours aron thats 24 measurements.i substituted the value for "number of measurements" thats what is given to us.